# How to clean the previous set interval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, audio, timer

I have the following code:

```
('#hometrainerSelectIntervall').on('change', function() {

      // function to change intervall
      function changeIntervall() {
        elemIntervall.innerHTML = textIntervall[counterIntervall];
        counterIntervall++;
        if (counterIntervall >= textIntervall.length) {
          counterIntervall = 0;
        }
      }

      // set the time to change intervall from input-data
      var time = parseInt($(this).find(":selected").data("time")) * 60 * 1000;

      if (this.value == 'timeWarmingUp')
      {

        // show/hide the corresponding boxes
        $(".hometrainerIntervallMuscleAndRestday, .hometrainerIntervallBoxing").hide(100);
        $(".hometrainerIntervallWarmingUp").delay(150).show(100);

        // loop/set the sound
        loop = setInterval(function(){$.playSound("/BETA/includes/boxing/sounds/BELL_HOMETRAINER.mp3")}, time);

        // define the text for the intervalls
        var textIntervall = ["<i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> STUFE 2 <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> ", "<i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i> STUFE 1 <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>"];

        var counterIntervall = 0;
        var elemIntervall = document.getElementById("intervallWarmingUp");
        var instIntervall = setInterval(changeIntervall, time);

      }

      else if (this.value == 'timeMuscleAndRestday')
      {

        // show/hide the corresponding boxes
        $(".hometrainerIntervallWarmingUp, .hometrainerIntervallBoxing").hide(100);
        $(".hometrainerIntervallMuscleAndRestday").delay(150).show(100);

        // loop/set the sound
        loop = setInterval(function(){$.playSound("/BETA/includes/boxing/sounds/BELL_HOMETRAINER.mp3")}, time);

        // define the text for the intervalls
        var textIntervall = ["<i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> STUFE 3 <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> ", "<i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i> STUFE 2 <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>"];

        var counterIntervall = 0;
        var elemIntervall = document.getElementById("intervallMuscleAndRestday");
        var instIntervall = setInterval(changeIntervall, time);

      }

      else if (this.value == 'timeBoxing')
      {

        // show/hide the corresponding boxes
        $(".hometrainerIntervallWarmingUp, .hometrainerIntervallMuscleAndRestday").hide(100);
        $(".hometrainerIntervallBoxing").delay(150).show(100);

        // loop/set the sound
        loop = setInterval(function(){$.playSound("/BETA/includes/boxing/sounds/BELL_HOMETRAINER.mp3")}, time);

        // define the text for the intervalls
        var textIntervall = ["<i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> STUFE 2 <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-up'></i> ", "<i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i> STUFE 1 <i class='fas fa-chevron-circle-down'></i>"];

        var counterIntervall = 0;
        var elemIntervall = document.getElementById("intervallBoxing");
        var instIntervall = setInterval(changeIntervall, time);

      }else{

        // hide all corresponding boxes
        $(".hometrainerIntervallWarmingUp, .hometrainerIntervallMuscleAndRestday, .hometrainerIntervallBoxing").hide(100);

        // clear all intervalls
        clearInterval(loop);
        clearInterval(instIntervall);

      }
});
```

How can I clean the interval selected by the selection as soon as an onchange has happened again?

Maybe it is also possible to optimize the code somehow I'm not the jquery/javascript expert (but it works) :D

With the current code the previous interval still runs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please put the `clearInterval` code in a `try catch` block and log the error if any

Comment: Their are no errors anything works but in the different sections the previous set interval still runs after changing :)

Comment: Depending on where you declare it, the `loop` variable may be out of scope and inaccessible to `clearTimeout`

Comment: Its the 'loop' and 'instIntervall' that i want to clear on change